# change the name of a font on os x

Tags: macos, fonts, font-faces

i was reading [an excellent article on HTML5](http://web.archive.org/web/20110726002116/http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html), and the title of the page and section headers had a very distinct font.  However, whereas fancy fonts on webpages are historically just images of text, the author of the page was using CSS3's `font-face` to host the font server-side, so even though i did not have the font on my computer, the webpage still displayed as the author intended.

i poked around the page's CSS and found the following:

```
@font-face
{
  font-family:"Essays 1743";
  src:url("f/essays1743-min.eot");
  src:local("Essays 1743"),url("f/essays1743-min.ttf")
}
```

i decided to try downloading the font:

```
$ wget http://diveintohtml5.org/f/essays1743-min.ttf
```

and then i dragged the downloaded file into "Font Book" (i'm using mac os x 10.5), but the name appeared as `e72ccf962bdd2bc1 - subset of Essays1743`, which means if i visit the page again, my browser will not recognize that i now have the font.

**the question:**
how can i edit the name of the font, preferably with a free program, so that it appears as "Essays 1743" in my 'Font Book', and my browser recognizes that i have the font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think my approach was all wrong, the font is [available for download](http://www.thibault.org/fonts/essays/) (w/ LGPL license).  i'm still interested in how i would go about renaming/editing fonts though.